# In lieu of (= in place of) vs instead of

Tags: prepositions, legalese

[Garner reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=Sd3byNeBdR4C&lpg=PA468&dq=%22The%20two%20were%20arraigned%20before%20a%20town%20of%20Montezuma%20justice%20and%20sent%20to%20the%20Cayuga%20County%20Jail%20in%20lieu%20of%20%24100%2C000%20bond%20or%20%2450%2C000%20cash%20bail.%E2%80%9D%22&hl=es&pg=PA468#v=onepage&q=%22The%20two%20were%20arraigned%20before%20a%20town%20of%20Montezuma%20justice%20and%20sent%20to%20the%20Cayuga%20County%20Jail%20in%20lieu%20of%20$100,000%20bond%20or%20$50,000%20cash%20bail.%E2%80%9D%22&f=false)

> *Instead of* will not always suffice instead of **in lieu of** —e.g.:
>
> “The two were sent to jail **in lieu of** $100,000 bond or $50,000 cash bail.”

[OED reads](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00132953) "in exchange or return for, as a payment, penalty, or reward for."

However I cannot grasp what the example exactly means.

Comment: There are certain contexts in which the formula _in lieu of_ is always used, and it wouldn't sound right to replace it with _instead of_. One such context is official arrangements, such as an employee dismissed without notice being given a month's salary _in lieu of notice_.

Comment: @KateBunting That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you voting to close, or providing an answer?

Comment: So do you use "in lieu of" instead of "instead of", or "instead of" in lieu of "in lieu of"?

Comment: Where is the blockquote taken from, please? Its example seems to strain the way 'in lieu of' is normally used (where 'instead of' **is** interchangeable). Legalese often redefines usage laws.

Comment: @KateBunting -my partner works a fixed day in a UK National Health Service hospital pharmacy, but, of course, urgent calls for medicines can come just before going-home time. There is no overtime pay, but if people have to work longer than their day, they may choose to record the extra time and take, at some other time, what they call 'TOIL', (Time Off In Lieu [of payment]).

Comment: Note that Garner is a lawyer in addition to a linguist and grammarian.

Comment: @TinfoilHat You say that like those are three different things. :)

Answer (score 3):

(Converting this to an answer as requested.)

There are certain contexts in which the formula *in lieu of* is always used, and it wouldn't sound right to replace it with *instead of*. One such context is official arrangements, such as an employee dismissed without notice being given a month's salary in lieu of notice, or, as Michael says, people taking 'time off in lieu' after working outside normal hours.

Comment: what is the context of OP? They were sent to jail **because** they didn't pay their (respective? I don't know the exact meaning of _or_ in OP) fines?

Comment: I would assume that no-one was willing to put up the $50,000 bail!

Comment: @GJC In your cited legal context, the two were subjected to a default alternative penalty absent the more desirable substitute of being released on bail.  This is a possible additional connotative nuance of *in lieu of / en lieu de* in legalese that wouldn’t occur with the more neutral *in place of / instead of*, a condition that could have been made more explicit by using things like *for/from/by/through lack of; for want/absence/fault of; in absence of, absent; lacking, wanting, failing, manqué*.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments to Kate Bunting’s answer, it appears that your question isn’t asking about “in lieu of” in isolation, but its function in the presence of “or” within the original context. This answer addresses that aspect of your question, leaving the discussion of “in lieu of” to Kate Bunting’s answer.

Your quote sets up a choice  between a ‘time in jail’ penalty and a monetary penalty.

The word “or” in the quote distinguishes between two forms of monetary penalty, one of which is called a bond and the other, bail.

The quote says that the ‘time in jail’ option was imposed instead of either monetary penalty.

Comment: Bit of a consolation prize.